# On Main activity unable to show popup in android Android Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android, mysql

To insert input values into mysql database I write insert() method

after insert method inserted data successfully I want to show Dialog popup with message "Success"

but I'm unable to execute the dialog.show() code :(

may be because of I pass MainActivity.this

```
Code in MainActivity 

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//call insert method to insert data into mysql
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        insert(name.getText().toString());                                      
                                    }
                                }).start();


}



public void insert(final String name){

//insert logic code
//returns true if success

if(true)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Record submited successfully!");
                          alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Success!");
                          alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                          alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,
                             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                                 dialog.cancel();
                                 }
                             })
                          .show();  

}

}//END class MainActivity
```

here is my problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `show()` on the main application thread, such as from `onPostExecute()` of an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: but I want to show dialog when data inserted how can I write it outside insert method ? :(

Comment: @ashish: I have no idea what "write it outside insert method" means. The code you have shown in your answer is being called from a background thread. While the insert-into-the-database logic itself can be in a background thread, updating the UI needs to be done from the main application thread.

Comment: @ashish: As I suggested in my answer, change your `Thread` to an `AsyncTask` and put the dialog work in `onPostExecute()`. Or wrap the dialog work in a `Runnable` and call `runOnUiThread()` on your `Activity`. Or wrap the dialog work in a `Runnable` and call `post()` on any handy widget. Or use an event bus like greenrobot's EventBus to raise an insert-completed event that is picked up on the main application thread and then shows the dialog. Or use a `Handler` and send it a message from the background thread.

Comment: thanks can you give me any example for the same i'm new to android dev

Comment: @ashish: Well, here's an example of using `AsyncTask` from my book: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/AsyncTask

Comment: thanks I did like this and it works :)
 `private class DialogTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
   
      protected String  doInBackground(String... urls) {
          return "Executed";
      }
      
    
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

             
            // code for pop up
         
      }
  }`